# MMC snap-ins notify method is not being called in 64 bit mfc/atl app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

MMC snap-ins notify method is not being called in 64 bit mfc/atl app.

Comment: I'm not a MMC domain expert, but I think even they will need a bit more to work with. I recommend asking yourself , "Could I answer a question like this in a field that I understand with the information provided?"

Answer (score 0):

replace the following line

```
HRESULT Notify( MMC_NOTIFY_TYPE event,
    long arg,
    long param,
    IComponentData* pComponentData,
    IComponent* pComponent,
    DATA_OBJECT_TYPES type);
```

with

```
HRESULT Notify( MMC_NOTIFY_TYPE event,
    long long arg, // long long, not long
    long long param,
    IComponentData* pComponentData,
    IComponent* pComponent,
    DATA_OBJECT_TYPES type);
```

Comment: Ah. I see what you're doing here. I think you still need more set-up on the question to make this easy to find for others who run into a problem like this.

Comment: or you could make it platform independent by using LONG_PTR instead of long long.